# Select and deselect in button onClick in android

Tags: android, button, onclick

When button is pressed its background state changes, I want that when I press the button again its background state will back to initial state. That means first click selects and second click deselects it. How could I do this?

```
orderBtn = new OrderButton(getApplicationContext());
orderBtn.setId(i);
orderBtn.setText(option);
orderBtn.setTextColor(Color
                .parseColor("#FFFFFF"));
orderBtn.setBackgroundResource((R.drawable.selector));
orderBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    v.setSelected(true);
    enabledButton = orderBtn.getId();
    deselectButtons();

}
});

public void deselectButtons() {
    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
        if (enabledButton != i)
            findViewById(i).setSelected(false);
}
```

Comment: Share code with us, what you already have achieved till now

Answer (score 3):

So, one thing you can do is this:

```
yourButton.setOnClickListener(new ClickListener(){
int check = 1; //When check = 1 ,you have your FIRST background set to the button

 @Override
 public void Click(View v){
    if(check == 1){
       yourButton.setBackground(R.drawable.secondBackground);
       check = 0;
    }else{
       yourButton.setBackground(R.drawable.firstBackground);
       check = 1;
    }
 }

});
```

Amyways, I remember I did this by modifying the selector that a toggleButton uses ,but I really,really don't have time to search my old projects and stuff...and as far as optimization goes, the selector should be a bit better ,but if you don't have tons of these buttons to check their backgrounds and keep changing them,you should be fine,I guess.

Let me know if this helped^^

Comment: I have already done what you are saying. If i press the button it goes selected state, i want press the button again and back to initial state.

Comment: oh I understand what you are saying...I am in a hurry now but I will come back with an answer later on after my exam

Comment: I will change my answer to the correct one in a few minutes.Sorry for taking so long ,was busy as hell today and still am...white night incoming..